# Pandas Dataframe Manipulation logic

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Can use please help with below problem:

Given two dataframes df1 and df2, need to get something like result dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
feature_list = [ str(i) for i in range(6)]
```

df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'value' :  [0,3,0,4,2,5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(6), columns=feature_list)

Expected Dataframe : 
Need to be driven by comparing values from df1 with column names (features) in df2. if they match, we put 1 in resultDf

Here's expected output (or resultsDf):

[image: resultDf]

Comment: why does the column `0` contains only `0`? And where did the index of the `resultDf` come from?

Comment: you are right. expectedDf is not correct. 0 should be 1 too. I will update the picture with correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
(pd.get_dummies(df1['value'])
   .rename(columns = str)
   .reindex(columns = df2.columns,
            index = df2.index,
            fill_value = 0))
```

---

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  1  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  1  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0  1
```